# Upload an artifact to Nexus 3 without Maven

Tags: maven, nexus, artifact

Is should be possible to upload an artifact (WAR file) to Nexus 3 repository without using Maven?

Comment: Which version of Nexus do you use?

Comment: Nexus 3.X @JFMeier

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT:**

You have two options, first if the repository format is raw you can upload any type of file using Direct Deploy as mentioned in their docs:

> Direct Deploy
>
> You can do an HTTP PUT of a file into /repository/your-repo-id/path-to-file
>     Using curl you can do this with:
>
> curl -v -u admin:admin123 --upload-file pom.xml 
>     http://localhost:8081/repository/maven-releases/org/foo/1.0/foo-1.0.pom

The second option is in case that the repository format is maven2 and then you can upload your war file with `mvn deploy:deploy-file` command , for example :

`mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=com.somecompany -DartifactId=project -Dversion=1.0.0 -DgeneratePom=true -Dpackaging=war -DrepositoryId=nexus -Durl=your-repo-url -Dfile=example.war`

Comment: But I need a pom file?

Comment: see my edit please, and let me know if it was helpful

Answer (score 0):

When you say “without Maven”, but you really mean “without using `mvn` at all” or just mean “without using Maven to build the WAR”?

If the latter, then I would suggest to use [`mvn deploy:deploy-file`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-file-mojo.html). This can deploy [arbitrary files](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/file-deployment.html) under a given GAV to any remote repository, including your Nexus 3.

Answer (score -1):

In the [documentation for Nexus Repository Manager 2.9](https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/2.9/reference/using-sect-uploading.html), it says:

> To upload artifacts to a repository, select a hosted repository in the Repositories panel and then click on the Artifact Upload tab.